# How to re-bind all Bootstrap javascript controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

In my Bootstrap website am getting HTML contents dynamically from AJAX jQuery script. In loaded content it have Bootstrap javascript controls like dropdown, tabs, collapse, etc., Since all these loaded after the DOM event it's all javascript not working.

Yes I know, I have to re-bind new javascript controls after loading the HTML using AJAX. Now I want to know **how to re-bind all Bootstrap javascript controls at once**.

Am getting new HTML content by code below and **it's working fine**

```
$('a').bind('click',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get(this.href,{},function(response){
        $('#app-content-body').html(response)
    });
});
```

Comment: First of all how you are loading your html contents, rebinding will depend on the way you load!! A code sample will be helpfull!!

Comment: am loading by this simple jQuery function $('a').bind('click',function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $.get(this.href,{},function(response){
       $('#app-content-body').html(response)
      });
     });

Comment: Please add this in your question by editing it!!

Answer (score 0):

You can either do this way:

```
$('a').bind('click',function(event)
{ 
      event.preventDefault(); 

      $.get(this.href,
      {},function(response)
      { 
           $('#app-content-body').html(response,function(){
                 //Bind the control events
           });
      }); 
});
```

OR

```
$('a').bind('click',function(event)
    { 
          event.preventDefault(); 
          $.when(
          $.get(this.href,
          {},function(response)
          { 
               $('#app-content-body').html(response);
          })).then(function(){
               //Bind the control events
          }); 
});
```

Comment: I already know where to do. I just want to know how re-bind all Bootstrap controls at once. Since loaded HTML is dynamic it may contain any Bootstrap javascript control.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the response html!!

Comment: Response HTML is dynamic. It may contain any HTML content which including any Bootstrap javascript controls like tabs or dropdown or nav menu or anything

Comment: Without knowing what controls can be there in html its very difficult to say whether or not you can re-bind them!! Or else you need to create instance of each control and initialize them irrespective of their presence in html!!! Or you can just send the whole html which again includes `stylesheet` and `js` files, but this approach is not recommended!!

Comment: In bootstrap, Initially without calling any functions how all controls binded on page load. If bootstrap is doing it by calling some function then can we recall it when we need?

Comment: Initially you will loading `bootstrap.js` file once the page is loaded right? that will bind all the events, functions inside it and after your ajax call you cannot simply expect to `bootstrap.js` to load again or if you have included it again in your response html file then definitely that should do the job!!